# weblogic cluster nodes health issues

Tags: java, server, weblogic, weblogic12c

We have a enterprise application deployed on a weblogic 12c cluster in production server.

Sometimes we have observered that Server nodes are not responding (Server health it is showing as **Ok**) but need to shutdown/restart it again to resolve the issue.

If anyone faced this issue Can you please help in finding root cause of the issue.

Appreciate your response.
 Thanks.

Comment: Are you up to date on your patches? Are you on exadata? Does your server use /dev/random or did you do the /dev/urandom workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that the health is showing ok, but there may be long running threads. I have seen sometimes weblogic does not show proper health. I think you should take a thread dump and heap dump. These dumps can show you proper health of weblogic